# How do I write every line to a separate file using awk?

Tags: awk

I would like to write every line of a txt-file to a separate file and use the first column as the name of the new file. The new file should then contain everything else in the line, but column 1.

So when I have:

```
example_1 a b c d
example_2 e f g h
example_3 j k l m
```

I want 3 separated files that are named example_1.mop, example_2.mop and example_3.mop and contain everything after the first column. So example_1.mop should contain a b c d and so on.

I almost found a way with

```
awk '{printf "%s\n", $2>$1".mop"}' file
```

but this only puts the second column in the new file. How can I tell awk to use everything else but the first column?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Mostly for the purpose of not allowing one's `perl` to get too rusty: `perl -anE '$,=" "; open my $f, ">", $F[0]; shift @F, say $f @F' input`

Comment: @William Pursell, sorry, I don't know perl. Could you maybe givre a little explanation to this one? Thank you very much!

Comment: In perl, the `-a` causes each line to be split into the array @F.  The first column is in `$F[0]`, so we open that file.  `shift` then discards the first element and shifts the rest of @F down one.  `say` prints the modified array.  The `$,=" "` just adds a single space between each entry in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work in any `awk`.

```
awk '
{
  first=$1
  $1=""
  sub(/^ +/,"")
  outputFile=first".mop"
  print >> (outputFile)
  close(outputFile)
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                    ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  first=$1               ##Creating first which has 1st field in it.
  $1=""                  ##Nullify 1st field here.
  sub(/^ +/,"")          ##Substituting initial space with NULL here.
  outputFile=first".mop"    ##Creating outputFile which has output file name in it.
  print >> (outputFile)  ##Printing current line into output file.
  close(outputFile)      ##Closing output file in backend.
}
' Input_file             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: The names of the files produced with this contain everything but the first column. Could this be because of the lien "outputFile=$0".mop""?

Comment: @Serrah, sorry there was a typo,I had fixed it now, please try my edited code, we should be Good here.

Comment: Yes, works like a charm. Thank you very much! And thank you for the very nice explanation. This is perfect

Comment: thank you for the explanation on how to accept the answer. I was a bit confused

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{out=$1".mop"; sub(/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*/,""); print > out; close(out)}' file
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks a lot! Could you shortly explain what the part "sub(...)" is doing, if possible? Thank you!

Comment: It's just removing the first field, i.e. the first sequence of non-spaces, and the spaces after it.

Comment: Ah, okay, I think, I get it. Thank you!

Comment: The difference between what I did `sub(/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*/,"")` and what @Ravinder did (`$1=""; sub(/^ +/,"")`) is that mine will work for any spaces (e.g. blanks and/or tabs) between fields in your input where his will only work for blanks, mine won't affect the spacing of the rest of your fields where his will convert every chain of white space to a single blank char, and mine won't force awk to recompile the data using OFSs for every FS. If your data is all single-blank-separated none of that really matters though.